Why axiom of choice involved here?
This is exercise 5.9 Thomas Jech set theory. Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i \in I}$ are disjoint families such that $|X_i| = |Y_i|$. Prove that
$$\bigg|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\bigg| = \bigg|\bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i\bigg|$$
by Axiom of choice.
My attempt: I'm pretty sure it's about the validity of the set
$$\{f_i:\text{some bijection between } X_i \text{ and } Y_i \text{ with } i \in I\}$$
To formalize this, for each $i \in I$, the sub-set
$$S = \{f : \text{ bijection between } X_i \text{ and } Y_i\} \subset Y_i^{X_i}$$
must not be empty due to $|X_i| = |Y_i|$. Thus, consider $P(S)$ and use the choice function:
$$g_i: P(S) \rightarrow \bigcup P(S)$$
on $S$ itself to pick uniquely $g_i(S)$, thus forming a function $i \rightarrow g_i(S)$. Is this the author intent?

A related older question: Axiom of choice: cardinality of general disjoint union.

The last part you wrote about $P(S)$ doesn't make sense to me, but the role of choice is that we use it to choose a bijection $f_i: X_i\to Y_i$ for each $i\in I$. Then $\bigcup_i f_i$ is a bijection $\bigcup_i X_i\to \bigcup_i Y_i$

did you spot anything invalid

@MathInquirer Your argument doesn't make sense to me, though it seems to have the correct goal of getting a sequence of bijections $f_i:X_i\to Y_i.$ The way to formalize it is to just note that ${S_i: i \in I}$ where $S_i$ is the set of bijections $X_i\to Y_i$ is a family of nonempty sets, so has a choice function $f,$ and then for $i\in I$ let $f_i = f(S_i).$
